# О слове "малохольный"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Имеется ли связь между словом "малохольный" и словосочетанием "мало холили"?

Answer (score 2):

Если верить [статье](http://hdl.handle.net/10995/26887) ([pdf](https://elar.urfu.ru/bitstream/10995/26887/1/ei_1978_05.pdf)), то прямой генетической связи нет. Там слово сближается с южнославянскими языками:

> Русск. **малохольный** соответствуют ц-слав. **млохавьство**, сербохорв. **mlahav** = **mlohav** "сла­бый", **mlahiv** "то же", **mlahaviti** "делать слабым", словен. **mlahav** "слабый, вялый", **mlahaviti** "ослабить, лишить сил", … **mlačen** "тепловатый" …

На более древнем уровне всё это возводится к корню, ***mlãk-**, который родственен праслав. корню ***mьlčati-**, откуда в том числе русск. **молчать**. Далее на индоевропейском уровне это возводится к корню ***mlke-** со значением «размягчать/таять».

Но также отмечается очевидное, что скорей всего русск. **малохольный** сближено со сложными словами на **мал-**: *малоумный*, *малоспособный* и *малопутный*.

---

У **Холить** совсем другая [этимология](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%85/%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Answer (score 0):

Смотря о какой связи идёт речь. Они созвучны, следовательно, имеется как минимум ассоциативная связь. Интеллекту человека свойственно (эволюционно) искать всякого рода косвенные связи между различными объектами. Поиск ассоциативных связей между словами лежит в основе так называемой "народной этимологии". В данном случае это не единственно возможная связь. Люди, увлекающиеся психологией, сразу видят связь со словом "меланхоличный"; знатоки других языков видят множество связей с похоже звучащими словами в этих языках; менее образованные люди автоматически вычленяют корень "лох". И только люди, которые занимаются этимологией профессионально, упорно не замечают всего этого.

Это загадка, требующая разъяснения. Наиболее естественным мне представляется такое объяснение: профессионалы действительно не видят этимологических связей там, где их нет. Но кто-то другой может предположить и всемирный заговор этимологов, скрывающих от простых людей истинные этимологические связи.

Comment: grizzly, неужели вы всерьез утверждаете, что "только люди, которые занимаются этимологией профессионально, упорно не замечают всего этого"?

Comment: @Серж Когда-то А.А. Зализняк подробно объяснял, почему в этимологии не очень ценятся игры с произвольными ассоциативными цепочками, с заменой / вычёркиванияем букв, с похожестью звучания в других языках и т.п. Всё это возможно в отдельных случаях, но требует лингвистического (или исторического) обоснования, а не просто игр разума, рождающих оригинальные и красивые версии.

Comment: grizzly, так я том же и говорю. Сейчас, перечитав ваш ответ, вижу, что неверно понял вашу мысль. Я подумал, что выступаете за народную этимологию. Поэтому был удивлен.

Comment: @Серж а чего плохого в народной этимологии?)

Comment: Плохого? Ничего. Просто это несерьезно. Вы сами это понимаете. )